# Is there an application that allows me to view Markdown files?

Tags: software-recommendation, previews, markdown

I don't want a WYSIWYG Markdown editor. I wouldn't mind if the app allows me to edit the file, as long as it renders it separately.

I know that Markdown is easy to read without rendering it but I often want to check to make sure my document looks right before uploading it to GitHub, so it would be nice to have an app to view Markdown documents.

Comment: This question should probably be merged with that one instead of being closed as a duplicate since Haroopad isn't covered by the other question.